# Post received by FromBody causes serializable error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, frombodyattribute

Here's the basic setup, I have an asp.net core webapi controller (in c#) with a post function like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody] string Name)
{
     //Do some processing with the "Name" argument...
     return Ok( "Success!" );
}
```

I'm trying to send the following raw JSON request body to this function:

```
{
    "Name": "Foo"
}
```

But when send a post request to this function with the body above, I get back the following error in the server console:

> "Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SerializableError'"

And this error on the client side

> {
>       "": [
>           "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1."
>       ]
>   }

I tried setting a break point at the beginning of the function but it doesn't even trigger! Why am I getting a serializable error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The serializable error is actually a parsing error from JSON.NET, but the problem actually has nothing to do with parsing JSON.

The real issue is that ASP.NET Core expects to parse a JSON body into an object/DTO. So you have two options you can use to fix the problem:

1. Make a simple DTO container object for your single parameter e.g.:

   ```
   public class SimpleObject { 
       public string Name { get; set; } 
   }
   ```
2. Instead of passing a full fledged JSON object in your request body, just use a simple string e.g: `"My parameter string"`

Answer (score 4):

You need a body in which json data will be parsed.

```
[FromBody] string Name
```

can not work with following json

```
{
    "Name": "Foo"
}
```

It needs a class

```
public class MyClass 
{ 
    public string Name;
}
```

Then pass it as

```
([FromBody] MyClass obj)
```

Or if it is single value, use JSON like

```
{
    [
       "Foo",
       "Foo1"
    ]
}
```

Then pass it as

```
([FromBody] List<string> obj)
```

Comment: Your second JSON is not valid, you define an object with an array directly inside of if, with no key. To match your last C# code, the JSON should be: `[ "Foo", "Foo1" ]`